# Зачем при использовании foreach для перебора enum используется typeof?

Tags: c#, foreach, enum

Разбираюсь с enum в C# и не понимаю, как работает и для чего нужен typeof в следующем примере:

```
public enum Direction
    {
        North,
        South,
        East,
        West,
        None
    }

static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        foreach (Direction d in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Direction)))
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{d} - {(int)d}");
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: Что просит метод `Enum.GetValues`? Наверно Type, верно? То есть некий объект, который содержит в себе информацию о типе. Чего тогда тут пояснять еще?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Спасибо, что-то сразу не додумался посмотреть на входные параметры метода.